# Saving File from web to Database c#

Tags: c#, web-services, model-view-controller, file-handling

Im making this website,where the user has a form in which they can choose a file from their computer,and upload it, but i don't know how i can use it. I'm using MVC and a Web Service also in C# where im handling the connection to the Database,where I have to save the file.The file can be a pdf,word or an image.
So the question is,how can I save it and also check its size.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ContentLength property of HttpPostedFileBase to get the size of the file - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.contentlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Then save the InputStream to a byte array

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    file.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
    bytes = stream.ToArray();
}
```

Next assign the byte array to a SqlDbType.VarBinary stored procedure parameter to save it back to the database - assuming this is SQL Server.